# Raspberry Pi in forever reboot loop crontab

Tags: raspbian, cron

I was trying to setup my raspberry pi in crontab to reboot every time at midnight, it didn't work, So I set it to run the command every minute, didn't work, so I put sudo in front of `reboot`, now I have a raspberry pi rebooting every minute, and I can't stop it. *facepalm* I know...

Does anyone have any idea how to stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have done all the progress on the `crontab`, I suggest resetting it to the default configuration.

Try the command below to reset it (the `-r` flag removes current crontab configuration.):

```
crontab -r
```

You can also use `crontab -e` and manually delete everything inside. Another option is `-l` to get a list of crontab configuration as an output.
In addition, You can use the `-u` flag to change someone else's configuration followed by the corresponding username.

---

If the `vi` editor bothers you, you can open/edit the `crontab` by adding `export VISUAL=nano;` before the `crontab` command with any flag you want like:

```
export VISUAL=nano; crontab -e
```

Comment: The `crontab -r` worked like a charm, I only have 5-10 seconds to clear it it again before it reboots again. doing it manually would take too long. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!